# Sum two ranges separately in one formula

Tags: google-sheets

How can I do one single formula to sum two ranges and display them in their respective column.

Here I'm using SUM formula in each cell but I'm sure there must be a single formula that can accomplish this.

Value 1 and Value 2 are the ranges to add them together in Sum row.

Here is an example picture.
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do it with formulas, probably can do it with a table and a sum row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `arrayformula` does not support `sum`, I suppose you could also do this in C12:

```
=arrayformula(C10:I10+C11:I11)
```

[image: output]

Comment: This accomplishes my request so easily that I feel kinda embarrassed, haha. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just learned this today @mau, you're not alone.

Comment: Yeah, it is so clean and simple. I love it! Have a pleasant day, my friend!

Comment: You too @mau :)

Answer (score 1):

Clear the formula you have in row 12 and then enter in C12

```
=index(mmult({1,1}, --C10:I11))
```

Change range to suit and see if that helps?

Comment: This is definetly what I need. Just a couple of questions. May you kindly explain the formula and what about most important, what about if I have 2 ranges?

Comment: For two ranges you can do =INDEX(mmult({1,1}, --({C10:I10; C11:I11})))